# Get inner most item in response string list

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I have this request getting the response, it is a list.

```
import requests
import json

lang='es'
title = 'this string, has a comma in it'
titleUrl = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=en&tl=%s&dt=t&q=%s" % (lang, title)
r = requests.get(titleUrl).text
d = json.dumps(r)
o = json.loads(d)
print o[0][0][0]
```

the request returns

```
[[["esta cadena, tiene una coma en ella","this string, has a comma in it",,,0]],,"en"]
```

But when I try and print `"esta cadena, tiene una coma en ella"` I only get `[`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `r` that is returned by Google is JSON (Well, kind of. Read on.)
- `d` is JSON of JSON.
- `o` is the original JSON again.
- Since `o` is just a string (in JSON notation), `o[0]` is a string containing its first character (and `o[0][0][0]` is the first character of the first character of the first character of the JSON string, which is identical to `o[0]`).

You never have an object decoded properly. You would need this:

```
r = requests.get(titleUrl).text
o = json.loads(r)
print o[0][0][0]
```

However, Google Translate only gives you something that looks like JSON - it is not, actually, valid JSON (as Google stopped supporting that API); so you will have to either prettify it, or parse it yourself.

```
import re
j = re.sub(r",,+", ",", r)
o = json.loads(j)
print o[0][0][0]
```